# In Python, if I return inside a "with" block, will the file still close?

Tags: python, return, with-statement

Consider the following:

```
with open(path, mode) as f:
    return [line for line in f if condition]
```

Will the file be closed properly, or does using `return` somehow bypass the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html)?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Yes, it acts like the `finally` block after a `try` block, i.e. it always executes (unless the python process terminates in an unusual way of course).

It is also mentioned in one of the examples of [PEP-343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) which is the specification for the `with` statement:

```
with locked(myLock):
    # Code here executes with myLock held.  The lock is
    # guaranteed to be released when the block is left (even
    # if via return or by an uncaught exception).
```

Something worth mentioning is however, that you cannot easily catch exceptions thrown by the `open()` call without putting the whole `with` block inside a `try..except` block which is usually not what one wants.

Comment: `else` could be added to `with` to solve that `try with except` problem. edit: added to language

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but to my knowledge `Process.terminate()` is one of the few (the only?) scenario that doesn't guarantee the call of a `finally` statement: *"Note that exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed."*

Comment: @RikPoggi [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit) is sometimes used - it exits the Python process without calling cleanup handlers.

Comment: Perhaps taunting the snake a bit, but what if I return a generator expression from within the `with` block, does the guarantee hold for as long as the generator keeps yielding values? for as long as anything references it? I.e. do i need to use `del` or assign a different value to the variable which holds the generator object?

Comment: What happens if something is constructed that depends on the open file - such as `return mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), path.stat().st_size)`? Will the file be closed, breaking the memory map? Or will the fact that the memory map depends on the file descriptor keep the file open for the scope of the returned object?

Comment: @davidA After the file is closed, the references are still accessible; however, any attempts to *use* the references to pull/push data to/from the file will give: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`.

Comment: @rplnt agreed. I'd love to see `with` supplemented with `except` and `else` blocks, the same as `try`, but of course without `finally` since it wouldn't serve any purpose. So `with ... except ... else ...` That way you could handle errors that occur when you enter the context handler (e.g. opening a file), or any uncaught errors within the handler (e.g. reading the file), without wrapping the thing in a confusing `try ... except ... else` block.

Answer (score 66):

Yes.

```
def example(path, mode):
    with open(path, mode) as f:
        return [line for line in f if condition]
```

..is pretty much equivalent to:

```
def example(path, mode):
    f = open(path, mode)

    try:
        return [line for line in f if condition]
    finally:
        f.close()
```

More accurately, the `__exit__` method in a context manager is always called when exiting the block (regardless of exceptions, returns etc). The file object's `__exit__` method just calls `f.close()` (e.g [here in CPython](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/39d1c2c7bcf7/Objects/fileobject.c#l1949))

Comment: An interesting experiment to show the guarantee you get from the `finally` keywrod is: `def test(): try: return True; finally: return False`.

Answer (score 50):

Yes. More generally, the `__exit__` method of a [With Statement Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) will indeed be called in the event of a `return` from inside the context. This can be tested with the following:

```
class MyResource:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('Entering context.')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print('EXITING context.')

def fun():
    with MyResource():
        print('Returning inside with-statement.')
        return
    print('Returning outside with-statement.')

fun()
```

The output is:

```
Entering context.
Returning inside with-statement.
EXITING context.
```

The output above confirms that `__exit__` was called despite the early `return`. As such, the context manager is not bypassed.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but there may be some side effect in other cases, because it may should do something (like flushing buffer) in `__exit__` block

```
import gzip
import io

def test(data):
    out = io.BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
        return out.getvalue()

def test1(data):
    out = io.BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
    return out.getvalue()

print(test(b"test"), test1(b"test"))

# b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x95\x1b\xb3[\x02\xff' b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x95\x1b\xb3[\x02\xff+I-.\x01\x00\x0c~\x7f\xd8\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: In function `test`, `out.getvalue()` happens before `__exit__` is executed, so the result is as expected.