# Row count in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, count, row

I am probably making a stupid mistake, but I can't find where it is. I want to count the number of lines in my csv file. I wrote this, and obviously isn't working: I have `row_count = 0` while it should be 400. Cheers.

```
f = open(adresse,"r")
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
data = [l for l in reader]
row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)

print row_count
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count how many lines are in a CSV Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108526/count-how-many-lines-are-in-a-csv-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get line count of a large file cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: The reason this happens is because the reader has "emptied" itself by creating the `data` list. The reader object provides a one-time for-loop, once you've worked through it, it's gone. That's why the row_count is being read as 0: there's nothing left in the reader at that point.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
with open(adresse,"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)
```

You are trying to read the file twice, when the file pointer has already reached the end of file after saving the `data` list.

Comment: Just a note: if you do list on the reader you will lose its advantage of being generator.

Comment: This reads potentially a lot of data into memory (although briefly) by creating that list. I think it's better to just do something like `entry_count = sum(1 for row in reader)` if we want entry count or `line_count = sum(1 for line in f)` if we want to count all rows in file (including header line).

Comment: @Erdős-Bacon I was just fixing the OP's code but that's correct

Comment: if you need to check the content of the file after counting the rows, you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file

```
# Reset file pointer for iteration
csv_file.seek(0)
next(reader)  # Skip header row
```

Answer (score 7):

First you have to open the file with `open`:

```
input_file = open("nameOfFile.csv","r+")
```

Then use `csv.reader` to open the csv:

```
reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
```

At last, you can take the number of row with the instruction `len`:

```
value = len(list(reader_file))
```

The full code is as follows:

```
input_file = open("nameOfFile.csv","r+")
reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
value = len(list(reader_file))
```

Remember that if you want to reuse the csv file, you have to make a `input_file.fseek(0)`, because when you use a list for the `reader_file`, it reads the whole file, and the pointer in the file changes its position.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with python3 and have pandas library installed you can go with

```py
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_csv('f.csv')

print(len(results))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a generator. It would do the job and keeps you safe from `MemoryError` of any kind

```py
def generator_count_file_rows(input_file):
    for row in open(input_file,'r'):
        yield row
```

And then

```
for row in generator_count_file_rows('very_large_set.csv'):
        count+=1
```

Comment: I like this @hellbreak. Do you have a similar solution for counting columns?

Answer (score 1):

*The important stuff is hidden in comments section of solution which is marked correct.*

#### Re-sharing Erdős-Bacon's solution here for better visibility.

Why ?
Because: It saves lot of memory without having to create list.

So I think it is better do this way

```
def read_raw_csv(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        csvreader = csv.reader(file)

        # count number of rows
        entry_count = sum(1 for row in csvreader)
        print(entry_count-1)  # -1 is for discarding header row.
```

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36973958/9592801) link for more info

Answer (score 0):

```
# with built in libraries
opened_file = open('f.csv')
from csv import reader

read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)

rowcount = len(apps_data) #which incudes header row

print("Total rows incuding header: " + str(rowcount))
```

Answer (score -6):

Simply Open the csv file in Notepad++. It shows the total row count in a jiffy. :)
Or
in cmd prompt , Provide file path and key in the command 
*find \c \v "some meaningless string" Filename.csv*

Comment: The OP wants to know how to fix the python script.