# How to find size of a csv and either be able to iterate on the reader object

Tags: python, csv, size, iterable

I want to have the number of rows for some CSV files.

I have found that can be easily done with len&list functions.

```
reader = csv.reader(base_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator="\n"
total_line = len(list(reader))
```

The problem is that after have the information about the number of row of the csv file, I would like to iterate on the reader object

```
for line in reader:
    id_revision = line[0]
...
```

Without the len&list function the iteration works, but when I calculate the number of row the iteration doesn't even begin.(Process finish without error)

Comment: does size mean how much space the file takes up in the file system? also `len(list(reader))` tells you the number of lines in csv, also `for line in reader` already iterates over each line, why do you need to do  `total_line = len(list(reader))` for it?

Comment: No for size I mean the number of rows. Anyway I have edited the question

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504056/row-count-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Actually yes. <code>data = list(reader)
        total_line = len(data)    for line in data:....<\code> With this code works.