# I'm trying to read a CSV file only if it i has between 200 and 400 records

Tags: python, csv, csvreader

I'm trying to read the CSV file only if has between 200 and 400 records. I want it to ignore otherwise. For some weird reason my code never reaches the **print(row)** line

```py
with open(file) as csv_file:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in csv_file)
    if (row_count>200 and row_count<400):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: `csv_file` is an iterator; after you loop over it with `sum` it's exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to read the data from the file. To get to the data you need to `csv_file.read()`
Even so, there's a lot of hassle as to the handling of the file.

I suggest using the `pandas` module because of its simplicity.

```
import pandas as pd

data =  pd.read_csv(r'filepath')
if 200<len(data)<400:
    print('True',len(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m still trying to figure out why, but you need to read the file again after performing the line count.

```py
with open(file) as csv_file:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in csv_file)

if (row_count > 200 and row_count < 400):
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb, that explains it - csv_file is an iterator; after you loop over it with sum it's exhausted

Comment: Also a good answer available here - >https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504076/4285029