# How do I print the total number of records from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a csv and I need to be able to print the total number of records how is this done? I have tried using sum statements and count but nothing seems to be working

Comment: please provide your code snippets, just asking question won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use pandas to import the csv file?

If so, here are some quick and easy options for obtaining the record count:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename)

len(df)
df.shape[0]
df.index
```

Otherwise, an alternative solution if you used `csv.reader(filename.csv)` is: 
`row_count = sum(1 for line in open(filename))`

(this solution was originally suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108526/count-how-many-lines-are-in-a-csv-python))

Comment: thanks fam this one worked..such a simple code I feel silly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open(adresse,"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)
print(row_count)
```