# Wrong row count for CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am processing a csv file and before that I am getting the row count using the below code.

```
total_rows=sum(1 for row in open(csv_file,"r",encoding="utf-8"))
```

The code has been written with the help given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108605/5658251).
However, the total_rows doesn't match the actual number of rows in the csv file. I have found an alternative to do it but would like to know why is this not working correctly??

> In the CSV file, there are cells with huge text and I have to use the encoding to avoid errors reading the csv file.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you have _cells with huge text_, csv parsers such as `pandas.read_csv` will read it correctly as opposed to `open` which reads the file line by line, not considering the _huge text_ as one.

Comment: @Chris yes. I have found alternate ways to read the rows correctly. But what is wrong with the above code that was suggested for using to count rows??

Comment: As I said, suppose your _huge text_ is two or more lines. In csv, this is considered as **one cell** which will be inside a single line. Nevertheless, `open` doesn't know it should be considered as one cell, and simply returns count of lines.

Comment: How many lines are in your file? Are you sure there is not a mix of `\r` and `\n` that might give your a wrong count?  or some `\n` or `\r` within some cell text?

Comment: I have run your code on a large file and it was providing me the correct output:

`python count_row.py 
 1715181568`
same result with `wc -l`

Comment: @Eswar can you provide us more info related what count you are getting what is apected

Comment: Counting the lines in the file (determined by \n or \r\n) is not the same as counting the csv rows because text in a value can include \n.

Comment: @Eswar go with pandas dataframe read the csv file like df=pd.read_csv("yourFile.csv") and then df.shape it will give all rows with columns number

Comment: @rahulsingh I have the correct way(with and without using pandas) to rows but I want to know why the above code isn't working. Chris pointed out right.

Comment: Just wanted to stress the importance to read the file with the correct encoding, as otherwise results could be completely off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have a csv file in which some cell's a multi-line text.

```
$ cat example.csv
colA,colB
1,"Hi. This is Line 1.
And this is Line2"
```

Which, by look of it, has three lines and `wc -l` agrees:

```
$ wc -l example.csv
3 example.csv
```

And so does `open` with `sum`:

```
sum(1 for row in open('./example.csv',"r",encoding="utf-8"))
# 3
```

But now if you read is with some csv parser such as `pandas.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./example.csv')
df
   colA                                    colB
0     1  Hi. This is Line 1.\nAnd this is Line2
```

The other alternative way to fetch the correct number of rows is given below:

```
with open(csv_file,"r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
     data = list(reader)
     row_count = len(data)
```

Excluding the header, the csv contains 1 line, which I believe is what you expect.
This is because `colB`'s first cell (a.k.a. *huge text block*) is now properly handled with the quotes wrapping the entire text.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem in here is because you are not counting rows, but counting newlines (either \r\n in windows or \n in linux). The problem lies when you have a cell with text where you have newline character example:

```
1, "my huge text\n with many lines\n"
2, "other text"
```

Your method for data above will return `4` when accutaly there are only `2` rows

Try to use Pandas or other library for reading CSV files. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(pathToCsv, sep=',', header=None);
number_of_rows = len(df.index) # or df[0].count()
```

Note that len(df.index) and df[0].count() are not interchangeable as count excludes NaNs.

Comment: I was able to get the correct number of rows without using pandas but are you suggesting that open function is counting the number of lines in each cell as well?

Comment: Yes, because open just reads file. It is not taking into account that this is CSV.

Comment: Chris summed what you're saying. Thank you.