# Python 3 Count number of rows in a CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, migration

Im having trouble getting the row count in a python 3 environment after migrating from 2.7. After several attempts the number of rows returned gives one. How do I get around a DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated in python 3 ?

```
             input_file = open("test.csv","rU")
             reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
             value = len(list(reader_file))
```

In the case of using python 3 Ive tried the following approach but Im still stuck with a 1.

```
             input_file = open("test.csv","rb")
             reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
             value = len(list(reader_file))
```

Comment: Remove `"b"` from `"rb"`.

Comment: Still gives me a 1

Comment: Could you share an excerpt from your CSV file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count how many lines are in a CSV Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108526/count-how-many-lines-are-in-a-csv-python)

Comment: `>>> len(list(csv.reader(open(r'new.csv'))))` works for me. Your file only has one line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using pandas you can easily do that, without much coding stuff.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

## Fastest would be using length of index

print("Number of rows ", len(df.index))

## If you want the column and row count then

row_count, column_count = df.shape

print("Number of rows ", row_count)
print("Number of columns ", column_count)
```

Comment: Much better though im still one row short

Comment: If you do read_csv and you're skipping bad lines, is there a way to get both the # of lines in the original CSV vs in the dataframe post-read?

Answer (score 0):

```
input_file = open("test.csv","rb") #rb is a read-in-binary format and 
#you can't count the number of row from binary format file

with open("text.csv",'r') as f:
file = f.readlines()
print(len(file))

# Data in my text file
# a
# b
# c
# d
# e

#The output of above code is 
#5 means number of rows is 5
```