# Add file name and number of rows to Python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, for-loop

this is my first post :). I have to check that each csv contains data - hence that the number of rows > 1 (accounting for header).

I am therefor trying to append to a dic the

- name of the file
- number of rows

So far, I get the name of the file in my dict but not the number of rows and instead the length of the path + file name

```
import glob
import csv

all_files = glob.glob(path + '*.csv')

dic = {}

for file in all_files:
    dic[file] = len(list(csv.reader(file)))
```

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this question was answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108526/how-to-obtain-the-total-numbers-of-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python) as @Metapod commented on your question.

In short, you should use `sum()` method for counting the number of lines efficiently:

```
for file in all_files:
    dic[file] = sum(1 for row in(csv.reader(file)))
```