# Returning value when exiting python context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x

Maybe this is a stupid (and indeed not very practical) question but I'm asking it because I can't wrap my head around it.

While researching if a `return` statement inside a call to a context manager would prevent `__exit__` from being called (no it doesn't), I found that it seems common to make an analogy between `__exit__` and `finally` in a `try/finally` block (for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885287/3471881) because:

```
def test():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        print("Good bye")
```

Would execute the same as:

```
class MyContextManager:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('Good bye')

def test():
    with MyContextManager():
        return True
```

This really helped me understand how cm:s work but after playing around a bit I realised that this analogy wont work if we are returning something rather than printing.

```
def test():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False
test()    
--> False
```

While `__exit__` seemingly wont return at all:

```
class MyContextManager:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return False

def test():
    with MyContextManager():
        return True

test()
--> True
```

This lead me to think that perhaps you can't actually return anything inside `__exit__`, but you can:

```
class MyContextManager:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return self.last_goodbye()

    def last_goodbye(self):
        print('Good bye')

def test():
    with MyContextManager():
        return True
test()
--> Good bye
--> True
```

Note that it doesn't matter if we don't return anything inside the `test()` function.

This leads me to my question:

- Is it impossible to return a value from inside `__exit__` and if so, why?

Comment: Note that the return value of `__exit__` has a defined meaning: If `__exit__` returns `True`, then any exceptions thrown inside the `with` context will be suppressed and will not propagate outside of the `with` block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It is impossible to alter the return value of the context from inside `__exit__`.

If the context is exited with a `return` statement, you cannot alter the return value with your `context_manager.__exit__`. This is different from a `try ... finally ...` clause, because the code in `finally` still **belongs to the parent function**, while `context_manager.__exit__` runs **in its own scope**
.

In fact, `__exit__` can return a boolean value (`True` or `False`) and it will be understood by Python. It tells Python whether the exception that exits the context (if any) should be suppressed (not propagate to outside the context).

See this example of the meaning of the return value of `__exit__`:

```
>>> class MyContextManager:
...  def __init__(self, suppress):
...   self.suppress = suppress
...  
...  def __enter__(self):
...   return self
...  
...  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb):
...   return self.suppress
... 
>>> with MyContextManager(True):  # suppress exception
...  raise ValueError
... 
>>> with MyContextManager(False):  # let exception pass through
...  raise ValueError
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError
>>>
```

In the above example, both `ValueError`s will cause the control to jump out of the context. In the first block, the `__exit__` method of the context manager returns `True`, so Python suppresses this exception and it's not reflexed in the REPL. In the second block, the context manager returns `False`, so Python let the outer code handle the exception, which gets printed out by the REPL.

Comment: I don't really understand the first sentence here. If I return a value inside `contextManager.__exit__` and don't return inside `with contextManager(): ...` - I still won't get a return value when I try.

Comment: @user3471881 That's because `__exit__` runs in its own scope, so it won't affect the return value of the context. Note that a function implicitly returns `None` if the control reaches the end of the function.

Answer (score 5):

The workaround is to store the result in an attribute instead of returning it, and access it later. That is if you intend to use that value in more than a print.

For example, take this simple context manager:

```
class time_this_scope():
    """Context manager to measure how much time was spent in the target scope."""

    def __init__(self, allow_print=False):
        self.t0 = None
        self.dt = None
        self.allow_print = allow_print

    def __enter__(self):
        self.t0 = time.perf_counter()

    def __exit__(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        self.dt = (time.perf_counter() - self.t0) # Store the desired value.
        if self.allow_print is True:
            print(f"Scope took {self.dt*1000: 0.1f} milliseconds.")
```

It could be used this way:

```
with time_this_scope(allow_print=True):
    time.sleep(0.100)

>>> Scope took 100 milliseconds.
```

or like so:

```
timer = time_this_scope()
with timer:
    time.sleep(0.100)
dt = timer.dt
```

**Not** like what is shown below since the `timer` object is not accessible anymore as the scope ends. We need to modify the class [as described here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) and add `return self` value to `__enter__`. Before the modification, you would get an error:

```
with time_this_scope() as timer:
    time.sleep(0.100)
dt = timer.dt 

>>> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Finally, here is a simple use example:

```
"""Calculate the average time spent sleeping."""
import numpy as np
import time

N = 100
dt_mean = 0
for n in range(N)
    timer = time_this_scope()
    with timer:
        time.sleep(0.001 + np.random.rand()/1000) # 1-2 ms per loop.
    dt = timer.dt
    dt_mean += dt/N
    print(f"Loop {n+1}/{N} took {dt}s.")
print(f"All loops took {dt_mean}s on average.)
```