# What is the best way to get the execution time spent of a single line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, time

I am trying to get the execution time spent on a single line of code. Doing this for multiple lines and/or writing code every time like in the example below is just frustrating. Is there a better way to do this? See the example below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv')
print('Time spent reading: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time))
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
df.head(n=100)
print('Time spent printing top 100: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time))
```

Comment: Use the [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html)

Comment: What is your goal here, to improve program performance, or just to give the user of your program some information on how long different tasks took?

Comment: The goal is to get how long it take to execute single line of code without writing the same pieces of code again and again. Like: start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: @MehmedB: that *doesn't tell us why you want to do that*. There are different reasons why you want to measure the time a line of code takes. Those different reasons lead to different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has variadic arguments (as well as keyword arguments), argument defaults, and has first-class functions. Basically this means you can pass in a function and optionally all of its arguments and keyword arguments into *another* function.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def record_time(task, args=(), kwargs={}):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    task(*args, **kwargs)

    return datetime.now() - start_time

print(record_time(print, ("test", )))
```

Just remember that a 1-ary tuple needs to be written as `('foo', )` and not as `('foo')`.

---

You can also use context managers that will allow you to time blocks of code rather than just individual functions.

```py
import contextlib

from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

@contextlib.contextmanager
def record_time():
    try:
        start_time = datetime.now()
        yield
    finally:
        print(datetime.now() - start_time)

with record_time():
    # Do a lot of stuff here...
    sleep(2)
    # Do more stuff if you like.

with record_time(): sleep(2)
```

By nature, it is [impossible to actually return the time this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077119/11633985) but printing it isn't hard.

Comment: I totally forgot context managers! Thank you so much for a working example!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the module `timeit`

**Example use**

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)

Out[1]: 0.25778120000006766
```

Thos code worked fine when using `python 3`.

You can run multiple cycles to be sure of any variability, and of course you can substitute the code between the ' ' with your own oneliner then.

More information can be found on the [doc page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for timeit

Comment: Nice, I learn about more tools in the Python standard library every day. I tested this, worried that eval would make the code in test less performant, but it was negligible from using the `datetime` subtraction method.

Comment: Note that running `timeit()` on a function that depends heavily on outside processes like I/O, such `read_csv` in the question, is not going to get you very accurate timings.

Comment: I was aware of timeit but I was looking for a way to 'timeit' a single line in a more complex algorithm where timing a single line for many times is almost unpractical due to time it take to execute it just for once. There are a lot of steps to the line of interest.