# NamedTemporaryFile() for clearing files after flask send_file

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run

I am using a flask server to return a processed image file after a request. I'm using google cloud run and from my understanding of the concurrency, I should be deleting files as I go to reduce memory usage of the instances that are spun up. For this purpose I've chosen to use NamedTemporaryFile() in a 'with' statement - my understanding is that the default behaviour is that once you exit the 'with' statement the temp file gets deleted.

This is the code I have to return the processed image.

```
   @app.route('/')   
   def hello():
      "image processing"
      with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
        cv2.imwrite(str(temp.name),img_processed) 
        return send_file(str(temp.name), mimetype='image/png')
```

However, since I am trying to return the function in the 'with' statement, will the temp file still be deleted?
Also am I using NamedTemporaryFile() correctly? The examples I've seen use temp.write but since I am using cv2.imwrite using temp.name was the method I came up with.
And is there a better way to delete files after flask send_file? - I've read about using  @after_this_request  but [Delete an uploaded file after downloading it from Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612366/delete-an-uploaded-file-after-downloading-it-from-flask) says it may be inconsistent.

Update: to use cv2.imwrite with NamedTemporaryFile(), I had to specify the extension of the tempfile using:
`NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')`
otherwise the code worked fine.

Comment: What exactly does NamedTemporaryFile() return?

Comment: sorry, should have made it more clear the return is part of my flask app function. I'll edit it now

Comment: I understood that - I mean what does the NamedTemporaryFile function return.

Comment: it's from the tempfile library. "Returns a file-like object that can be used as a temporary storage area"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885287/62138) and running a quick test, this works as intended.

Test:

```
In [13]: from pathlib import Path

In [14]: from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

In [15]: def deltest(delete=True):
    ...:     with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=delete) as temp:
    ...:         return temp.name


In [16]: file = deltest()

In [17]: Path(file).exists()
Out[17]: False

In [18]: file = deltest(delete=False)

In [19]: Path(file).exists()
Out[19]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, since I am trying to return the function in the 'with'
> statement, will the temp file still be deleted?

I think it is, according to https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile:

> The file is created securely, using the same rules as mkstemp(). It
> will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit close
> **when the object is garbage collected**)

The return statement would garbage collect the `temp` variable and the object therefore.

> The examples I've seen use temp.write but since I am using cv2.imwrite
> using temp.name was the method I came up with.

You can use the write method if you write an encoded string:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def temp_fx():
  with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    print(temp.name)
    temp.write('abc'.encode())
    return 1

temp_fx()
```