# in python, is it safe to return from within a "with" block?

Tags: python-3.x, return, with-statement

in the following example code:

```
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        return file.read()
```

does the return statement cause any potential instability?
does the "with" operator still provide its safeguards under these circumstances?
since the return happens, and nothing is executed after the return statement, does the with operator still perform its closing operations that ensure the stability of the file operations and close file pointers?

EDIT:
This seems to answer the question:
[In Python, if I return inside a "with" block, will the file still close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885217/in-python-if-i-return-inside-a-with-block-will-the-file-still-close)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, if I return inside a "with" block, will the file still close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885217/in-python-if-i-return-inside-a-with-block-will-the-file-still-close)

Comment: aside from @kcsquared above.   Why would you do this ?